# Laravel-5.7 not create folder resources\views\layouts

Tags: laravel-5.7

I'm using PHP 7.2.12 and Composer 1.7.3.

When I execute the command `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my_project` the project is created, but the folder `resources\views\layouts` is not created and neither the files that are inside of it. Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer. To create the folder resources\views\layouts I needed execute

```
php artisan make:auth
```

this command create the structure initial the layout to login of the laravel

Answer (score 0):

Laravel-5.7 will not create folder

resources\views\layouts by default, you have to create it manually.

Please check this:
http://prntscr.com/lusq6a

Thank you